# extending a class with a generic without additional generics

Tags: typescript

For the following code:

```
class Generic<T extends string> {
  constructor (private input : T) {}
  PRINT () {
    console.log(this.input)
  }
}

class Extended extends Generic {
  ANOTHER_PRINT() {
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to pass the generic for an extended class? I can easily solve it with:

```
class Generic<T extends string> {
  constructor (private input : T) {}
  PRINT () {
    console.log(this.input)
  }
}

class Extended<T extends string> extends Generic<T> {
  ANOTHER_PRINT() {
  }
}
```

But then it feels like there's code duplication.

Error is:

```
Generic type 'Generic<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

Comment: No, `class X<T> extends Y<T> {...}` is the easiest and only reasonable way to do it.  TypeScript lacks "higher kinded types" (of the sort requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)); there's no way to talk about generic types in the abstract, so you can't just say something like `X extends Y` if you mean `X<T> extends Y<T>`.

Comment: You *could* use/abuse [the support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) (the closest TS has to built-in higher kinded types) to extend generic superclasses without redeclaring generic type parameters, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6Xrem).  But the cure looks worse than the disease, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I could write this up as an answer but if so it'll be tomorrow (it's sleepytime in my time zone)

Comment: @jcalz indeed the answer cure looks worse than the disease. I'd rather just do `class Extended<T extends ConstructorParameters<typeof Generic>[0]> extends Generic<T>`. But feel free to write up the answer. I'll accept it, since it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TypeScript doesn't have *higher kinded types* of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), you can't talk about generic types in the abstract.  If you have a generic type/class/interface like `Foo<T>`, you can mention it like `Foo<string>` or `Foo<number>` or `Foo<U>` for some other generic type parameter `U`, but you cannot just say `Foo` to mean the general type function.  The easiest and most straightforward way to do what you want is therefore to be redundant and specify the type parameters in both cases:

```
class ExtendedOne<T extends string> extends Generic<T> { /*..impl..*/ }
```

The closest you can get to what you want to do here is to take the `Generic` constructor *value* and pass it into a higher order function that extends constructors in its implementation.  If you do it right, the compiler can [infer a generic constructor in its output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-constructors) and save you from having to manually write out the type parameter.  It could look like this:

```
const Extended = extend(Generic, {
    ANOTHER_PRINT() {
        console.log("ME ALSO SAY:");
        this.PRINT()
    }
})
    
/* const Extended: new <T extends string>(input: T) => Generic<T> & {
    ANOTHER_PRINT(): void;
} */

const n = new Extended("hello");
/* const n: Generic<"hello"> & {
    ANOTHER_PRINT(): void;
} */
n.PRINT(); // hello
n.ANOTHER_PRINT(); // ME ALSO SAY: hello
```

You can see that `Extended` is "magically" a generic constructor with the same type parameter as `Generic`.  The implementation of `extend` is something like

```
function extend<A extends any[], R extends object, T>(
    parentCtor: new (...args: A) => R,
    sub: T & ThisType<R & T>
):
    new (...args: A) => R & T {
    const c = class extends parentCtor { };
    Object.assign(c.prototype, sub);
    return c as any;
}
```

and having `A` and `R` be generic parameters for the arguments and return type of the constructor function `parentCtor`, the compiler can perform its higher kinded type magic.  The [`ThisType<T>` intrinsic utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) gives the compiler a hint that the `this` inside of `ANOTHER_PRINT`'s implementation is the same as the extended class's instance type.

So, this works, but it's a lot of effort and weird-looking code just to avoid writing `<T extends string>` and `<T>`.  There are reasons to want to implement generic constructor-producing functions, but I wouldn't say this is one of them.

And so I still recommend just writing out the type explicitly, despite being a little redundant.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiCmA7eAnAlsAPAFWvAHgC5IAmMEh6iA5gHzQDeAUNK9MAPaIUoCuwhDigAUAB3QA3MMWhpEo3oQBc0bAEpG0AL4s2ABQBKASQBy2YRuZtr7LhA4h4AOhAdqwwgAs0EJ3IWEarqsOjpMoJAwAKJEpPAkAPLIOHixiGTQPHJ0qcTpMAjI6FjY9FZsAIImCdgAElEGAPqGpuaWwTac3A7Oru4ARACyUdAVADIAygnQExUAmkr9agDcHdZePk4tZhYdoUxMAGa8iAJoXLmkmBWX+dBgiACeANoAugA00Aa3GRwARgAreACT6lYQdURgFBIQgAYUEKBUyAA7tBhE4MVDqBAVBUNABeegGd4dCC8P4qXAAMlU3gg2EeongmG+NNKTDUSg6KLRGKcWJxowJROgbMYHS6FHY0Hx7HAUB+MEh0MQcIRmi0q2sCUBwMI-KgaGoiGEwCc4g4gkIjPgnzJfxWHWhhF4KEQ0sg9yeqzCksI0BieRI8RlP2EhVQGE+5VYVRq9Sa2za4psbElPRcbmEQxG4ymM3mi0dqdYG18Sd21lCQSYAHoAFS2bj+wNxEhI+ColIEIPkSjZWjCfyKSnCuBISMleg0mOjap1BrNYw7TnQCQcNAkH3Qeu1g5+6Du2U81vpeLZzzwECuJarBtNqWIFQR4qYfqX68cfrTlOVecJpdWgsFR103bddyYRAtmXNplmgWta2gD9XEgpw4wXRMYIsOCEOgYZRkmaZZgWJCrxQoA)